# Parsing out a boolean-search abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, boolean-logic

I'm trying to build a Python parser that will take "complex" boolean search strings and parse them into multiple simpler strings, one to a line. e.g.

"(A OR B) AND (C OR D) AND (E OR F)" converts to:

A AND C AND E

A AND C AND F

A AND D AND E

etc...

This will need to be scalable, so that eventually other boolean operators can be used (e.g. NOT, proximity operators, etc) and arbitrary parenthetical depths are supported. I've worked out the parts that parse the string and create an abstract syntax tree (AST). The part I'm having trouble with is conceptualizing how to interpret the AST once it's built.

My thought was to create an algorithm that walks the AST and converts it more or less in place, but the implementation escapes me.

For a simple example:

```
    AND                                  OR
OR - | - OR       =>               OR   --|---  AND
 |        |                        |             |
A-B      C-D                  OR   -    AND    B - D
                              |          |
                         AND  -   AND   B - C
                          |        |   
                        A - C    A - D
```

The idea is that this is a first pass, and on a second pass you split up the "OR"s into separate lines when printing out the result.

But I'm not sure what you would "do" with the first tree to walk through it and convert it to the second. And this quickly gets complex if you add another AND to the input string. Am I making this too hard?

Comment: So basically you want to convert `CNF` (Conjunctive Normal Form) into `DNF` (Disjunctive Normal Form)? Even just considering `and`, `or` and `not`, then you might want to read [this](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~bromille/Papers/cnfdnfmfcs.pdf) about its complexity. Having said this, there should be an extensive literature of algorithms for doing it, possibly even implementations in `python`. The duplicate link above proves what I just said, upvoted. :-)

Comment: If you really want to simplify the expression, have a look at [Karnaugh Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or at the [Quine McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed - getting pointed in the right direction before I get too far down the wrong path. I'm not sure the question should be downvoted though, since it could still be useful for someone else (like me) who doesn't know about CNF/DNF.